# File not uploading while using multer

Tags: javascript

I am creating an employee payroll application where i want to upload and download xlsx file in records section. Controller works fine. Postman gives response as file uploaded successfully but the file is not uploaded in public/docs directory. Am i doing something wrong while serving static directory.

Static directory serving code.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(process.cwd(), 'public')));
```

Router to uploading file

```
router.post('/', protect, upload.single("file"), fileUpload)
router.get('/download', fileDownload)
```

Controller for uploading file

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        if(!fs.existsSync(directory)){
            fs.mkdirSync(directory)
            console.log("Running 123", directory);
            cb(null, directory)
        }else{
            console.log("Directory already exists", directory);
            cb(null, directory)
        }
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, Date.now() + "-" + file.originalname)
    }
})

const upload = multer({storage, fileFilter: (req, file, callback) => {
    if(['xls', 'xlsx', 'NUMBERS'].indexOf(file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length-1]) === -1){
        return callback(new Error('Wrong extension type'));
    }
    callback(null, true);
}})

const fileUpload = function(req, res) {
    let recordPath = path.join(process.cwd(),'public/docs/' + req.file.filename)
    importToDb(recordPath);
    fs.unlinkSync(recordPath);
    res.json({'msg': 'Employee record uploaded and successfully imported', 'file': req.file});
};

const fileDownload = function(req, res) {
    let template = path.join(process.cwd(), '/public/docs/Employee_Record_Template.xlsx');
    res.download(template);
};
```

Directory Structure is

```
payroll
-bin
-public
    -docs
    -emailTemplates
    -images
    -javascripts
    -stylesheets
    -fonts
-src
    -config
    -controllers
        -api
    -middlewares
    -models
    -routes
app.js
```

Comment: In your Multer config, what is `directory`?

Comment: @Phil `const directory = path.join(process.cwd(), 'public/docs');` is my directory

Comment: Just an FYI but `req.file.path` has the full path of the file, you don't need to build it

Comment: Why would you expect the file to be in `public/docs` when you specifically delete it with `fs.unlinkSync(recordPath)`?

Comment: @Phil what is the solution.?

Comment: Uh, don't delete the file ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Phil that is to delete if different type of file is added.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. In your `fileUpload` function you get the file, pass it into `importToDb()` then **explicitly delete it** before sending back a success message